# Vector, iterators and const_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have just started learning vectors and iterators. I can't understand 2 things. Why can I change the constant iterator and what is the role of the "*"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> inventory;
    inventory.push_back("inventory1");
    inventory.push_back("inventory2");
    inventory.push_back("inventory3");
    vector<string>::iterator myIterator;
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    cout << "Your items:\n";
    for (iter = inventory.begin(); iter != inventory.end(); iter++)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Any iterator can change value, unless it is declared `const`. A `const_iterator` refers to the object being "pointed to" as `const`. The `*` is to retrieve the value the iterator "points" to.

Comment: `const_iterator` doesn't mean that the iterator is a constant, but that you cannot change the item it refers to.

Comment: That code is correct. I just cant stand why "iter", which is const_iterator, can change his value and i cant understand what you mean about the"*"

Comment: I guess i should read more to understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: @gprex - The iterator is essentially a special pointer to the type of element in your `vector`, in this case a `string`. This "special pointer" must be **dereferenced** to access the `string` object.

Comment: @owacoder - Don't confuse the poor guy with pointers. They are hard! And to be strict, a pointer is a kind of random access iterator. Not the other way round. :-)

Comment: I thought that can be explained with simple words to "poor guys" like me.

Comment: Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: Michael Dawson Beginning C++ through game programming third edition.                                  I have also The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup but i decded it will be too hard for me...

Answer (score 9):

When you do `iter = inventory.begin()` it makes `iter` refer to the first string in your vector. `iter++` moves it to refer to the next string.

In the output you use `*iter` as way to access the string that `iter` refers to. In the first output that will be `inventory1`.

The slight confusion about the constness is that

```
vector<string>::const_iterator   iter;
```

is an iterator that refers to things that are constant, while

```
const vector<string>::iterator   iter;
```

would make the iterator itself constant, but allow you to modify the object it refers to.

Comment: So, with * i let the iterator to output it ? Before that it only refers to but with * i give him access ?

Comment: But what is the role here ?:'myIterator = inventory.begin();
 *myIterator = "inventory4";
 cout << "\nYour items:\n";
 for (iter = inventory.begin(); iter != inventory.end(); iter++)
 {
  cout << *iter << endl;
 } of the * ?

Answer (score 5):

> Why can I change the constant iterator

You have a non-`const` iterator of type `vector<string>::const_iterator`. You can change it because it is non-`const`. Being a `const_iterator` means that dereferencing it returns a `const` reference to an object. Which means that the referenced object cannot be modified.

The iterator is non-`const` because the type `vector<string>::const_iterator` does not have a `const` qualifier.

> what is the role of the "*"

It is the *dereference operator*. It returns the object that the iterator is currently pinting at. More exactly, it returns a reference to the object. Another name for it is *indirection operator*.